# Add classname to the_category() function?

Tags: filters, css, categories

is it possible to use `add_filter` or something similar to add the `slug` of the category as classname to the `the_category()` function?

Right now when using `the_category()` the output looks like this …

```
<ul class="post-categories">
    <li>
        <a href="http://mysite.com/something" title="" rel="category tag">News</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to somehow get this …

```
<ul class="post-categories">
    <li class="category-news">
        <a href="http://mysite.com/something" title="" rel="category tag">News</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or something similar, at least some classname with the `slug` of the category so I can select it via CSS?

Thank you in advance, matt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First locate `the_category()` in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category). Scroll down to the bottom of the page to "Source Code". There is a link "`the_categfory()` is located in ...". Click the link, you will be redirected to the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L249). Alternativly open the file `wp-includes/category-template.php` in your IDE or editor.

Now search for `function the_category()`. You will see that the function calls another function `get_the_category_list()`. Search for this function too. And now read the code and search for `apply_filters()` or `add_action()`

As you can see, there is only one `apply_filters()` call at the end of the function. If you read the code carefully, you know now that you can only filter the *complete html* created by `the_category()`.

There are several ways to modifiy the html. DOMDocument is one of them, a good old `preg_replace_callback()` another one.

```
function add_class_callback( $result ) {

  $class = strtolower( $result[2] );
  $class = str_replace( ' ', '-', $class );
  // do more sanitazion on the class (slug) like esc_attr() and so on

  $replacement = sprintf( ' class="%s">%s</a>', $class, $result[2] );
  return preg_replace( '#>([^<]+)</a>#Uis', $replacement, $result[0] );

}

function add_category_slug( $html ) {

  $search  = '#<a[^>]+(\>([^<]+)\</a>)#Uuis';
  $html = preg_replace_callback( $search, 'add_class_callback', $html );

  return $html;
}

add_filter( 'the_category', 'add_category_slug', 99, 1 );
```

Thats easy, isn't it? Apply a filter on `the_category` hook. Search for `<a followed by some chars but not >[group the chars until <]</a>`, pass the result to the callback function. The callback function retrieve an array with all search results, we pick the last one, this is the text of the link. Then create a class from the text, please sanitize this very well (by your own). Last but not least, insert the class attribute and return the generated result back to `preg_replace_callback()` weher it is replaced with the search result.

Yes, I like DOM manipulation very much... not ;)

Oh, I forgot. You can do this also with jQuery. Search for the class '.post-categories', grep all link tags inside a list tag, walk over the result and get the href attributes, convert it to a propper classname, add the class with `.addClass(class)` to the link tag.

Comment: Thank you, perfect. `apply_filters()` however didn't work for me. Had to use `add_filter()`

Comment: Eeehm yes... it was late at night as I wrote the code ;)

Comment: While this is a great answer, personally I ended up just doing my own loop with `$catTerms = get_terms('category');`...`<?php foreach ($catTerms as $t) : ?>`. That way I could also use `$t->slug` for the class (to avoid having to worry about escaping it myself) and I also used `$wp_query->get_queried_object();` to set an "active" class to the currently viewed category.

Answer (score 2):

While sanitizing for classNames can be very hard in some languages i prefere @powerbuoy's comment and figured that out:

```
function yourTheme_category_class($thelist){
  $categories = get_the_category();

  if ( !$categories || is_wp_error($categories) ) {
    return $thelist;
  }

  $output = '<ul class="post-categories">';
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $output .= '<li class="category-' . $category->slug . '"><a href="' . esc_url(get_category_link($category->term_id)) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';

  return $output;
}
add_filter( 'the_category', 'yourTheme_category_class');
```

i hope that may help, cheers